# Creating a translucent responsive triangle in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a translucent responsive triangle with only one side of it's border colored in a div

I found a way online that uses 2 triangles and placing them on top of one another but the problem is I would like the triangles to be translucent so the background image of the div can be seen

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZPjB.jpg

Thanks alot for your help and any help would be much appreciated!

```css
.container {
 width: 33.33%;
 height: 500px;
 background: blue;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
 
.triangle {
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 padding-top:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
.triangle:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-top:-500px;
 border-top: 500px solid transparent;
 border-right: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi! 
I have added the code snippet to the main post, run it in full page and resize your browser; it's responsive but I want to make the outer border have a 2px solid blue border(like https://i.imgur.com/ZxHc3jV.jpg), is it possible?

Comment: I don't get why you're trying to achieve it this way, why not a normal png/jpg at the corner ?

Comment: The container will have an background image, the triangle will hold the caption for that image.. TL;DR: it's the design I have to code out :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like below:-

```css
.triangle{
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  border-bottom:87px solid red;
  border-left:87px solid white;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hi! 
I have added the code snippet to the main post, run it in full page and resize your browser; it's responsive but I want to make the outer border have a 2px solid blue border(like https://i.imgur.com/ZxHc3jV.jpg), is it possible?

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2013/03/triangles-in-css.html